# Connecting Yahoo mail with Evolution

Tags: evolution, mail

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and want to add my yahoo mail account to Evolution, how can I do that
There are many resources available but no step to step accurate guide is there

Comment: did you unlock the feature for using an external mailclient with your yahoo mail account in the yahoo-webinterface? read this in a thread and it seems a common problem to not being able to use an external email client with yahoo mail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily configure Evolution to Work with Yahoo! Mail IMAP service.
Go to; Edit > Preferences in the Evolution menu, in the Evolution Preferences dialogue, click the Mail Accounts button on the left, click the add button on the right, click the forward button on the Evolution Account Assistant dialogue, Enter your name and E-mail address, click the forward button, you will be taken to the Receiving Email dialogue, use the following settings;

Receiving Email dialogue;

Server Type: IMAP+

Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com

Username: Yahoo! ID without "@yahoo.com"

Security: SSL encryption

Authentication Type: Password

check mark: Remember Password

click forward, you will be taken to the Receiving Options, do the following;

check the Check for new messages in all folders checkbox and click forward, you will be taken to the sending Email dialogue, use the following;

Sending Email dialogue;

Server Type: SMTP

Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com

checkmark: Server requires authentication

Security: SSL encryption

Type: PLAIN

Username: Yahoo! username without "@yahoo.com"

checkmark: Remember password

FOR POP3 SERVICE

you will need a paid account or a free account that will allow pop3 mail delivery, for the free account only some specific countries are allowed to use pop3, Yahoo UK is one of them,fortunately,you can create an account using addresses associated with these from anywhere,see this link; http://www.techiecorner.com/126/free-yahoo-pop3-email-account-yahoo-mail-sg-and-hk/

You may be able to change an existing free account to allow pop as well, see here; http://picobit.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/yahoo-mail-free-pop-access/ the results are mixed though.

On how to use evolution with yahoo pop3 service, see if this old thread is still relevant; http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=829046

Comment: I can though set the Y! account now, and also I can send through Yahoo, but I can not check my Yahoo email, only option I see is Gmail account(which I added earler)

Comment: I restarted the Evolution and it is there :), thank you for such a nice writeup!

Comment: Screenshots here would make this answer perfect!

Comment: Great instructions. Very helpful.