# Evolution does not ask for password with Yahoo

Tags: evolution, password, yahoo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting Yahoo mail with Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20075/connecting-yahoo-mail-with-evolution)

Yahoo will not send or receive mail. Evolution never asks for a password. I will quit
using yahoo after this but I would like to download my mail. Thanks for any help.
I think the problem is that all the services do not want to use pop so I need to tell
it that it is a smtp server. Is there any link that would help with setting up yahoo
mail with Evolution. b

Answer (score 0):

I now know that you have to change the account to a plus yahoo account. Then the 
receiving server is plus.pop.mail.yahoo.com port 995. Outgoing server plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com use SSL and port 465  Cost 19.99 a year. I have 
other accounts so I will just forward my messages one at a time.